# Can I add formatting rules for any arbitrary language in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, formatting

Visual Studio seems to have fairly extensive formatting rules for the languages it supports, but if there's a way to specify formatting rules for other languages, I haven't found it. I would expect things like, collapsing code blocks based on brace position, automatically closing braces and indenting blocks, etc, to be configurable for any language, but I don't see how. The specific language I'm looking at is QML, if that makes a difference.

I've found the option to link a specific editor to a file extension, but this doesn't quite do the job as the formatting rules for two languages aren't necessarily the exact same. This also seems to break syntax highlighting*. If it's possible to write an extension to add support to VS for other languages including formatting rules, I'm totally willing to do that, but I haven't seen anything like that.

*This is likely QML specific - the QT VS extension includes syntax highlighting for QML, but frustratingly does not add support to automatically format it, which makes typing it a chore. This reinforces my belief that adding this behavior with an extension is not possible.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/getting-started-with-language-service-and-editor-extensions?view=vs-2019